# PHP- display a value in bracket in excel

Tags: php, excel

I am converting HTML to excel file.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
?>
<tr><td>(8.47%)</td></tr>
```

Here i want to display **(8.47%)** in display in excel but when i open the excel file it automatically convert and display as **-8.47** .

I want my value to be display as **(8.47%)** not as **-8.47**.

Comment: try this way `"(8.47%)"`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama i tried this. but it is now displaying as "(8.47%)"

Answer (score 0):

Does quoting works ? Like you do in excel.

```
<tr><td>('8.47%)</td></tr>
```

Edit:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
?>
<table>
    <tr><td>(8.47%)</td></tr>   
</table>
```

I just add `<table></table>` around and works for me

Comment: its display same as ('8.47%).

Comment: Did you use a library ? Like PHPExcel or other ?

Comment: No i am simply converting html to excel.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me as it download the php file. Maybe I do something wrong ?

Comment: My bad i misconfigure the enviromement.

But like this it works for me

`
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
?>
<table>
 <tr><td>(8.47%)</td></tr> 
</table>
`